# What ES6 features are supported in JSX?

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm using **React with JSX** with [react-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tools) to compile the JSX code to JavaScript.

What ES6 features are supported in JSX with the `harmony` option enabled?

Comment: Good question. It reminds me that we should add JSX to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to kangax for [the compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#jsx)

**Update**: Just [use babel (previously named 6to5) to compile your JSX](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/). It's faster and has better es6 support anyway.

Comment: What about modules? (export default etc... ) ?